# Use emoticon in subject line for sendgrid email

Tags: html, email, sendgrid, emoji

How can I use an emoticon in a subject line in an email?

I would like to use the [rocket](http://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/146/travel-places/rocket). I tried adding the HTML decimal entity in the subject string. However this is rendering as the characters and not the rocket.

`"Launch &#128640;"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subject lines don't get rendered as HTML in email clients. What you want to do is send the literal character, ie: `Launch` .

Comment: how do I get that value? i.e. what is the string? is it the unicode character?

Comment: It is a unicode character!  If the language you're using supports it, then simply copy and paste my sentence in the above post. If not then you'll have to use the codepoint here: http://graphemica.com/%F0%9F%9A%80

Answer (score 0):

We use sendgrid via java and the following string text to provide this html code effectively in the subject line, `\uD83D\uDE80`, so for example, `[dlh.io] Initial Data Sync Complete \uD83D\uDE80`, works like a charm.

[image: Email from dlh.io]